# Simple GRID layout for mobile app tile home page CSS + HTML only

Tags: android, html, css

I want to have a grid layout on my mobile app homepage and I want to do it without using 3rd party libraries.

I found some examples online but they all seem to have on flaw: the height of them is fixed, as in my case, i would like to have the height and width of the whole thing to have the actual full screen real estate of the mobile that is running on.

How I want it to look on all platforms:

[image: frontscreen example]

The above image is a lucky scenario where everything lines up, but as soon as I add the png images into the tiles, it gets off.

Here's my attempt:

```css
.tileCollector {
 padding-left:3px;
 padding-right:3px;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
}

.homepageStatus {
 background-color: #4d82b8; /*var(--color5);*/
 height:100%;
 padding:30px;
}

.StatusMessage1 {
 display:block;
 padding-left: 1.0vh;
 font-size: calc(1em + 5vmin);
 line-height:1.5em;
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family: 'Open-Sans';
 color:white;
}

.StatusMessage2 {
 display:block;
 padding-left: 1.0vh;
 font-size: calc(1em + 5vmin);
 line-height:1.5em;
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family: 'Open-Sans';
 color:white;
}

.StatusMessage3 {
 display:block;
 padding-left:1.0vh;
 font-size: calc(1em + 5vmin);
 line-height:1.5em;
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family: 'Open-Sans';
 color:white;
}

.tileIcon {
 padding-top:30px;
 color:white;
 height:50%;
}

.tileContainer {
 padding:5px;
}

.tile {
 font-size: 30px;
 color:white;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#tileTopLeft {
 background-color: #FFC000; /*var(--color1);*/
}
div#tileTopRight {
 background-color: #92D050; /*var(--color2);*/
}

div#tileBottomLeft {
 background-color: #A6A6A6; /*var(--color3);*/
}

div#tileBottomRight {
 background-color: #FF5050; /*var(--color4);*/
}

.tile-icon-label {
 font-family:'Oswald';
}
```

```html
<table class="tileCollector">
  <tr colspan=2 height="40%">
    <td colspan=2 class="tileContainer" id="StatusContainer">
      <div id="homepageStatusDiv" class="homepageStatus">
        <span class="StatusMessage1">Message 1</span>
        <span class="StatusMessage2">Message 2 </span>
        <span class="StatusMessage3">Message 3</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30%" >
    <td class="tileContainer">
      <div class="tile" id="tileTopLeft" ng-click="">
        <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
          <tr style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <td style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="center">
              <img class="tileIcon" src="icons/frontpage/icon1.png" class="contrast"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <td style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="center">
              <span class="tile-icon-label">Option 1</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tileContainer">
      <div class="tile" id="tileTopRight">
        <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
          <tr style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <td style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="center">
              <img class="tileIcon" src="icons/frontpage/icon2.png" class="contrast"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <td style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="center">
              <span class="tile-icon-label">Option 2</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30%">
    <td class="tileContainer">
      <div class="tile" id="tileBottomLeft">
        <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
          <tr style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <td style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="center">
              <img class="tileIcon" src="icons/frontpage/icon3.png" class="contrast"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <td style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="center">
              <span class="tile-icon-label">Option 3</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tileContainer">
      <div class="tile" id="tileBottomRight">
        <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
          <tr style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <td style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="center">
              <img class="tileIcon" src="icons/frontpage/icon4.png" class="contrast"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <td style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="center">
              <span class="tile-icon-label">Option 4</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, there would be PNG images inside every tile, right in the middle, above the "Option #" text. I would like these also to be resizable and responsive as well as the text. 
Is that possible?

Should I totally ditch the table idea and go with divs, or there's no actual difference?

Answer (score 0):

I think flexboxgrid could be your solution. You can read/learn more about the grid here: http://flexboxgrid.com/ :) Good luck!